# Unit Testing a Basic Function with npm nock (hostname undefined)

Tags: node.js, axios, chai

Updated:
I have a basic async function that I want to unit test. I am using npm's nock to mock the response from the server. Everytime I run this small test script I get the error that the hostname is undefined:
I don't understand why I get this error when I try to call the function from a test. It works fine when I run the script and when I make the call in postman. I feel like I'm looking over something that's super basic?

Here's the unit test code:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const getSorted = require('../src/karma').getSorted;
const nock = require('nock');

describe('Sorting', function () {
    it('should return karma in DESC order', function (done) {
        let expectedKarmas = { users: ['nikki', 'person', 'nolan'], karmas: ['3', '2', '1'] }

        let karmaApi = nock(`http://server:4567/`);
        karmaApi.get('/getsorted/DESC')
            .reply(200,
                [['bmlra2k=', '3'], ['cGVyc29u', '2'], ['bm9sYW4=', '1']]
            );

        let recievedKarmas = getSorted("DESC");
        console.log('recievedKarmas:::', recievedKarmas)
        assert.equal(recievedKarmas, expectedKarmas);
    });
});
```

Here's the original function:

```
let axios = require("axios");
let atob = require('atob');

//end point is "server:4567"
let KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT = process.env.KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT;
module.exports = {

getSorted: async function (direction) {
        if (direction !== "ASC" && direction !== "DESC") {
            console.error("INVALID SORTING DIRECTION: %s. PLEASE PROVIDE ASC OR DESC", direction);
            return;
        }
        try {
            let url = `http://${KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT}/getsorted/${direction}`;
            console.log('URL IS:', url)
            let jsonResult = await axios.get(url);
            let sorted = { users: [], karmas: [] };
            jsonResult.data.forEach(element => {
                //users are stored in the database encoded, atob() decodes them back into strings
                sorted.users.push(atob(element[0]));
                sorted.karmas.push(element[1]);
            });
            return sorted
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('ERROR HERE', error)
        }
    }
```

Full error:

```
  Sorting
URL IS: http://undefined/getsorted/DESC
recievedKarmas::: Promise { <pending> }
    1) should return karma in DESC order
ERROR HERE { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:80
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'undefined',
  host: 'undefined',
  port: 80,
  config:
   { url: 'http://undefined/getsorted/DESC',
     method: 'get',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     data: undefined },
  request:
   Writable {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options:
      { protocol: 'http:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        path: '/getsorted/DESC',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        hostname: 'undefined',
        port: 80,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/getsorted/DESC',
        proto: 'http',
        host: 'undefined:80' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 0,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest:
      ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        _header:
         'GET /getsorted/DESC HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nHost: undefined\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/getsorted/DESC',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'http://undefined:80/getsorted/DESC' },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function] }


  0 passing (24ms)
  1 failing

  1) Sorting
       should return karma in DESC order:
     AssertionError: expected {} to equal { Object (users, karmas) }
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test-karma.js:21:16)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

So I know the test is at least hitting the original `getSorted()` function because `ERROR HERE` gets logged. But I don't understand why the host and host name is undefined. I'm explicitly saying 'server:4567'.

I think I'm making a silly mistake because this is just me trying to call a function from a basic unit test.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried logging your variable KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT before the call?  The env variable of your test process may be not set correctly.

Comment: yes, I tried, and I also put in 'server:4567' directly just in case :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your test truly unitary.  You should not call directly HTTP call in a unit test.  This is because you would need the other server to be running and therefore it is not unitary any more.

There is are mutiple ways to avoid this.

1 - Proxyquire
ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire

Require your file for the test but replace some dependencies by your own.

The downside is that you don't know exactly what Proxyquire may replace.  You delegate to another library.

```
const proxyquire =  require('proxyquire');
const assert = require('chai').assert;

const fakeStub = {} // This is some sort of fake or stub that prevent http call.

const getSorted = proxyquire('../src/karma', {axios: fakeStub }).getSorted; // Requires using your fake

describe('Sorting', function () {

    // If your test framework allow async function in test use it instead of done.  
    it('should return karma in DESC order', async function () {
        let expectedKarmas = { users: ['nikki', 'person', 'nolan'], karmas: ['3', '2', '1'] }

        let recievedKarmas = await getSorted("DESC"); // since it is async you have to wait otherwise it may be a promise
        assert.equal(recievedKarmas, expectedKarmas);
    });
});
```

2 - Adding an override hook

More control and may have some special mode that avoid axios call.

The downside is hard to manage the state of the `require`.  When requiring again the module axios may be still overridden.

```
let axios = require("axios");
let atob = require('atob');

//end point is "server:4567"
let KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT = process.env.KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT;
module.exports = {
    overrideAxiosHook: (fakeAxios) => {
        axios = fakeAxios
    }
    // return the users sorted by amount of karma in directions of ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending)
    // object returned has a users array and a karmas array
    getSorted: async function (direction) {
        if (direction !== "ASC" && direction !== "DESC") {
            console.error("INVALID SORTING DIRECTION: %s. PLEASE PROVIDE ASC OR DESC", direction);
            return;
        }
        try {
            let url = `http://${KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT}/getsorted/${direction}`;
            let jsonResult = await axios.get(url);
            let sorted = { users: [], karmas: [] };
            jsonResult.data.forEach(element => {
                //users are stored in the database encoded, atob() decodes them back into strings
                sorted.users.push(atob(element[0]));
                sorted.karmas.push(element[1]);
            });
            return sorted
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('ERROR HERE', error)
        }
    }
}
```

The test

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const {getSorted, overrideAxiosHook} = require('../src/karma');
const fakeStub = {} // This is some sort of fake or stub that prevent http call.

describe('Sorting', function () {

    before((done) => {
       overrideAxiosHook(fakeStub)
       done();
    });

    //If using done
    it('should return karma in DESC order', function (done) {
        let expectedKarmas = { users: ['nikki', 'person', 'nolan'], karmas: ['3', '2', '1'] }

        getSorted("DESC").then((recievedKarmas) => {
            assert.equal(recievedKarmas, expectedKarmas);
            done();
        });

    });
});
```

3 - Adding axois in the module.export and using this.axios

Same downside as #2 but on function less

```
let atob = require('atob');

//end point is "server:4567"
let KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT = process.env.KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT;
module.exports = {
    axios: require("axios")
    // return the users sorted by amount of karma in directions of ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending)
    // object returned has a users array and a karmas array
    getSorted: async function (direction) {
        if (direction !== "ASC" && direction !== "DESC") {
            console.error("INVALID SORTING DIRECTION: %s. PLEASE PROVIDE ASC OR DESC", direction);
            return;
        }
        try {
            let url = `http://${KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT}/getsorted/${direction}`;
            let jsonResult = await this.axios.get(url);
            let sorted = { users: [], karmas: [] };
            jsonResult.data.forEach(element => {
                //users are stored in the database encoded, atob() decodes them back into strings
                sorted.users.push(atob(element[0]));
                sorted.karmas.push(element[1]);
            });
            return sorted
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('ERROR HERE', error)
        }
    }
}
```

4 - Use the a real http call

Downside need another running server.

```
process.env.KARMABOT_API_ENDPOINT = 'server:4567';
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const getSorted = require('../src/karma').getSorted;

describe('Sorting', function () {
    it('should return karma in DESC order', async function () {
        let expectedKarmas = { users: ['nikki', 'person', 'nolan'], karmas: ['3', '2', '1'] }

        let recievedKarmas = await getSorted("DESC");
        assert.equal(recievedKarmas, expectedKarmas);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm planning on using nock to mock the http response but I wanted to get a basic function/unit test working first. I suppose I should intercept the axios.get request first and not worry about making a direct http request.

Comment: I will try it out and comment back on here when I get a chance.